How to convert an array to an array in rust?
I would like to convert an array of one type [T; N] into an array of another type [U; N] where U: From<T>. Is there any language syntax or std functionality that allows this without a heap allocation? If not, why not? Is there something about the language design that makes doing this difficult to implement?

Nothing about the From trait says the result must be constructed in-place. If U and T can have different sizes, I don't see how this could work without allocation.

@Bergi Quite the opposite -- the compiler knows how big U is which means that it knows how much space is needed for N instances of U. Based on your argument, no array could ever possibly be constructed without a heap allocation, which we know is false.

@cdhowie Oh, I missed "heap allocation". All I was trying to say is that in general a new space needs to be allocated for the new value; regardless whether that is on the stack or on the heap.

Use .map():
let strings: [String; 3] = [1, 2, 3].map(|num| num.to_string());

This is different from the Iterator method of the same name; this method is directly on arrays and converts from [T; N] to [U; N] using the given functor.

I'm not a Rust expert, but how does this guarantee all allocations will happen on the stack? (I assume we can ignore num.to_string() here - or is the small-string-optimization for common digit char strings a guarantee too?)

@Dai Because in Rust arrays are values, just like structs. Allocation doesn't implicitly happen. You either need to invoke a heap-allocated wrapper like Box or Arc, or you need to be using a type that does its own allocation like Vec or String.

@Dai To be clear, this doesn't mean no heap allocations will happen at all, it means no heap allocations will happen to construct the array itself. The example code will allocate, but it's the Strings that allocate. If you're converting e.g. a [u16; N] into a [u8; N] using this method then no allocations happen.
